# Build query with different kind of terms for SolR

Tags: java, regex, solr, lucene

I have a webapp that could execute a search through an url query on SolR.

The results are received as a Document object.

my query is look like : `q=Book:Harlan AND Book:Coben AND ..`, it works fine.

```
String[] word = searchedWord.trim().split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(word[i])) {
        if (i > 0) {
            query.append("%20AND%20");
        } 
        String utf_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(word[i]), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

But i need to enforce the kind of searched terms, because when the searched term is like an exact term : `"Harlan Coben"`, this code split it in two word `"Harlan` and `Coben"`

Per example, my webapp should be able to search:

Exact terms: `"Harlan Coben"`

Multiple terms: `shakespeare harlan coben`

Multiple mixed terms: `shakespeare "harlan coben" coben` or `shakespear "harlan coben"` or `"harlan coben" coben`

The URL to call SolR is encoded in UTF-8 to replace special characters..

How should i proceed ? by regular expressions ? or is there another way ?

**------ EDIT --------**

**To be more specific,** All of these characters could be *"@(!ùéàç"* or *chinese/russian or anything else characters (unicode?) from a specific language*.

I need to match them and separate them to prepare the SolR query.

**Example:**

If the search term is : `coben "Harlan Coben" s(554603)hakesdpeare Straße Привет`
My regex should match and give me this result:

```
 coben
 "Harlan Coben"
 s(554603)hakesdpeare
 Straße
 Привет
```

Then i need to concatenate each of them with `AND Book:` or juste `Book:` to have a query as below:

`q=Book:coben AND Book:"Harlan Coben" AND Book:s(554603)hakesdpeare AND Book:Straße AND Book:Привет`

I tried `("[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)+"|[a-z]+)(?:\s+|$)` from @fge (thanks for that), but it match only with [a-z], i tried this with `\\p{all}` but didn't work..

Any idea ?

**------ END EDIT --------**

Thanks for help !

Comment: So if a search string containing spaces is enclosed in double quotes, you do not want it to be split up ?

Comment: yes i need to keep the exact term like "harlan coben" and not two different terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the correct regex to match any characteres (including chinese or other languages) and give me each word of the search:

Example if the search is :

> harlan coben "harlan coben"

Each match found will be:

> harlan 
>   coben 
> "Harlan coben"

Here is the used code:

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?>\"[^\"]+\"+)|(?>[^ ]+)+");
Matcher match = PATTERN.matcher(motRecherche);
match.reset();
int iM = 0;

while(match.find()){
    if(iM > 0){
        query.append("%20AND%20");
    }

    String utf_encoded = CommonUtils.escapeSolrQuery(match.group(0));
    query.append(":"+utf_encoded);
    iM++;
}
```

Another thing about SolR, it's needed to escape some special characters **+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \** , SolR provides a client class called ClientUtils and a method escapeQueryChars() that i change for me:

```
public static String escapeSolrQuery(String searchWord){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchWord.length(); i++) {
          char c = searchWord.charAt(i);

          if (c == '\\' || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '!'  || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == ':'
            || c == '^' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '~'
            || c == '*' || c == '?' || c == '|' || c == '&'  || c == ';' || c == '/') 
          {
            sb.append('\\');
          }

          if(c == '\"' && !searchWord.matches("\"[^\"]+\"")){
              sb.append('\\');
          }
          sb.append(c);
        }
       return sb.toString();
    }
```

Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex but it will be quite complicated; in this case you need an alternation. Here it is assumed that you only have letters in your search term:

```
("[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)+"|[a-z]+)(?:\s+|$)
```

(note that the alternation order is *important* here!)

Example:

```
public final class Bar
{
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("(\"[a-z]+(?:\\s+[a-z]+)+\"|[a-z]+)(?:\\s+|$)",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        tryAndMatch("\"Harlan Coben\"");
        tryAndMatch("shakespeare harlan coben");
        tryAndMatch("shakespeare \"harlan coben\" coben");
    }

    private static void tryAndMatch(final String input)
    {
        final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(input);

        System.out.printf("INPUT: -->%s<--\n", input);

        while (m.find())
            System.out.printf("Term -->%s<--\n", m.group(1));

        System.out.println("END INPUT");
    }
}
```

---

Now, as to substitution into URLs, be aware that `URLEncoder` is *not* made to encode URL components, it is made to encode `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, in which a space becomes `+` and which does not have the same escape chararcter sets than neither a URI path or fragment.

The most accurate solution would be to use URI templates. This allows you to write templates such as:

```
http://my.site/?q={query}
```

where `query` is any Unicode string and this will encode it for you (self promotion: if you are interested I have a [library to do that](https://github.com/fge/uri-template)).

The second is to use Guava 15.0+, it has a [set of escapers especially made for URLs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html).

Comment: thanks for you help, this could help, but my problem is to define the query with differents kind of terms as describe above

Comment: yes this is what i need ! many thanks for your help ! i'm very bad in regular expression lol

how can i replace the character [a-z] by every type of character ? because, the word could be in chinese or russian or it could contains some special characters like " ( " or "-".

I also need to do some operations on each word, i will find how to do that but can you tell me with this regex, how can i use singly each single word or exact expression ? is it with group ?

Per example, for an input like "\"Harlan Coben\" coben", "harlan coben" could be `m.group(1)` and coben `m.group(2)` ?

Comment: For all letters you can use `\p{IsL}` instead of `[a-z]` (in a Java string that will give "\\p{IsL}"). As to separating each word, you should do it in a separate method. If the match is between quotes, remove the quotes and use a simple `.split("\\s+")` to obtain the different words.

Comment: Thanks again, could you see my edit ? i provided more details and an example. On my side, i will continue to search and try, thanks !